# complexity of finding the hampath of length $k$ in a graph with $n$ vertexes where $k < n$

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs

A simple question:

What would be the complexity of finding whether a hampath of length $k$ exists in a graph with $n$ vertexes where $k < n$?

Would this be in NP-complete or just NP?

Comment: Assume you can solve the problem in polynomial time. Then solve the problem for the largest possible value of $k$. What do you think now?

Comment: @Juho I am not still sure. The problem being NPC would rely on the fact that ordinary hampath problem be polynomially converted to $k$-hampath problem. But newly-converted problem may be more difficult (NP-hard) or some other cases. (It is true that finding a hampath in a graph with $n-1$ vertexes would be NPC, but it's not clear whether finding a $k-hampath$ in a graph with $n$ vertexes would be NPC.

Comment: @user7585, So if you want to solve HAMPATH on a graph $G$, can you construct a graph $G'$ where $|V(G')| = |V(G)|+1 = n+1$ such that a length $k=n$ path in $G'$ guarantees that the only vertices used are vertices that were in $G$?

Comment: @LukeMathieson Hmm. But that seems problematic. There would be basically ${}_nC_k$ choices for this kind of construction - which does not determine the problem in any sense. (If this is the only way, then the problem would be NP-hard or NP, but we cannot deduce this from a possible construction alone.)

Answer (score 2):

Purely for clarity I'll lay out the definitions first, then give a reduction for your problem, so skipping a little ahead shouldn't cause a problem (if it does, start a bit earlier ;) ).

The two problems:

> **Hamiltonian Path (HP)**
> *Input:* A graph $G$.
> *Question:* Does $G$ contain a path with $|V(G)|$ vertices?
>
> **Not Quite Longest Path (NQLP)**
> *Input:* A graph $G$ and an integer $k < |V(G)|$.
> *Question:* Does $G$ contain a path on $k$ vertices?

Now, what we want to prove:

> **Lemma 1:** NQLP is $\mathcal{NP}$-complete.

Of course this has two parts, membership and hardness.

> **Proposition 2:** NQLP $\in \mathcal{NP}$

*Proof:* Given an order set of vertices we can easily check that it is of length $k$ and forms a path in $G$. $\Box$

> **Proposition 3:** HP $\leq_{m}$ NQLP

*Proof:* Let $G$ be an instance of HP and for convenience let $n = |V(G)|$. We construct an instance $(G', k)$ of NQLP by taking $G'$ as $G$ with an additional, disconnected vertex $v$, i.e. $V(G') = V(G)\cup \{v\}$ and $E(G') = E(G)$. Thus $|V(G')| = n' = n+1$. We choose $k = n < n'$. This construction is clearly computable in polynomial time.

Claim: If $G$ has a Hamiltonian path, $G'$ has a path of length $k$.

By definition, the Hamilton path includes all vertices of $G$, as $G'$ has $G$ as an (induced) subgraph, this path exists in $G'$. Moreover it is of length $n = k$.

Claim: If $G'$ has a path of length $k$, $G$ is has a Hamiltonian path.

If $G'$ contains a path of length $k$, it cannot include the added vertex $v$, as it has no incident edges (except the trivial case where $G$ was one vertex, but then we have a symmetry which does our work for us). Therefore it must include every other vertex in $G'$ (as $k = n' -1 = n$), as $G' - v$ is simply $G$, $G$ must be Hamiltonian. $\Box$

*Proof of Lemma 1:* As HP is $\mathcal{NP}$-complete, Prop. 3 proves that NQLP is $\mathcal{NP}$-hard. Then combining Propositions 2 & 3, we have proved Lemma 1. $\Box$